# i have Warning in my admin front view when i remove the underscore then front view is not loading as befaore

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions

WARNING | Property name "$_template" should not be prefixed with an underscore to indicate visibility

```
 <?php

namespace Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Block\Adminhtml\System\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class LogoutSubmit extends Field
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    public $_template = 'Marstranslation_Marstranslation::system/config/logout_submit.phtml';
    private $dataHelper;
    /**
     * @param Context                                      $context
     * @param \Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Helper\Data $dataHelper
     * @param array                                        $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Marstranslation\Marstranslation\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Remove scope label
     *
     * @param  AbstractElement $element
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $element->unsScope()->unsCanUseWebsiteValue()->unsCanUseDefaultValue();
        return parent::render($element);
    }
    /**
     * Return ajax url for loginSubmit button
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAjaxUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('marstranslation/system_config/logout/');
    }

    /**
     * Generate loginSubmit button html
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getButtonHtml()
    {
        $button = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Button'
        )
            ->setData(
                [
                'id' => 'marsLogoutSubmit',
                'label' => __('Logout'),
                'class' => 'action-primary'
                ]
            );

        return $button->toHtml();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This variable will be **protected** so change it to protected

```
protected $_template = 'Marstranslation_Marstranslation::system/config/logout_submit.phtml';
```

Either use the **$this->setTemplate()** or ignore the warning. You can check  level

**Error  10** A critical error with severity level 10 prevents an extension from passing technical review.

**Warning  8**  A severity level 8 warning does not prevent an extension from passing technical review. Developers are encouraged to resolve any issues that trigger a level 8 warning.

**Warning**   **6**       A severity level 6 warning does not prevent an extension from passing technical review. Developers are encouraged to resolve any issues that trigger a level 6 warning.

Here is [detail](http://docs.magento.com/marketplace/user_guide/extensions/review-code-validation.html)

command for checking

```
phpcs --error-severity=1 --warning-severity=8
```

Comment: how i can check warning type is 6 or 8?

Comment: @MRIZWAN added the command